# Here Map Marker Click issue with debuggable:false in Android

Tags: android, heremaps-android-sdk

With the Latest sdk release from HERE map we are able to perform click on marker only when we set debuggable true in our App settings. App is working fine in Debug mode as we set debuggable true in this case . When we release apk we cant set debuggable true as it will be a security risk .

mapFragment?.pickMapItems(point2D, 2.0, MapViewBase.PickMapItemsCallback { pickMapItemsResult ->
if (pickMapItemsResult == null) {
return@PickMapItemsCallback
This value is coming as Null always with debuggable false
}
}
Version info : 4.16.1.0.12797-release
debug {
minifyEnabled true
shrinkResources true
zipAlignEnabled true
debuggable false
manifestPlaceholders = [crashlyticsCollectionEnabled: "false"]
proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
testCoverageEnabled false
}

I try to get Marker point by clicking but getting null value when i set debuggable:false with true its working as expected

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.